# jQuery UI sortable: clone order from one list to another list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists, which are supposed to have the same order, e.g.

```
<ul id="mainList">
  <li title="li1">First item</li>
  <li title="li2">Second item</li>
  <li title="li3">Etcetera</li>
</ul>

<ul id="copiedList">
  <li title="li1">Copy of first item</li>
  <li title="li2">Copy of second item</li>
  <li title="li3">Copy of etcetera</li>
</ul>
```

On the main list, I apply the jQuery UI sortable plugin with `$('#mainList').sortable()`. If the main list is sorted into a different order by the user (e.g. the new order is `li1, li3, li2`), I would like to reorder the copied list as well.

Could anyone please provide me a best practice on how to achieve this?